# Admin & User Middleware Authentication - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

This is my admin middleware authentication

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    if(Auth::check())
    {
        if(Auth::user()->hasRole('administrator'))
        {
            //return redirect('admin/dashboard/home');
        }

        else if (Auth::user()->hasRole('operator'))
        {
            return redirect('user/dashboard/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

This is my user middleware authentication

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::check())
    {
        if(Auth::user()->hasRole('administrator'))
        {
            return redirect('admin/dashboard/home');
        }

        else if (Auth::user()->hasRole('operator'))
        {
            //return redirect('user/dashboard/home');
        }

       return $next($request);
    }

}
```

In my AuthenticateUsers.php

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if(Auth::check())
    {
        if(Auth::user()->hasRole('administrator'))
        {
            return redirect('admin/dashboard/order/all');
        }

        else if (Auth::user()->hasRole('operator'))
        {
            return redirect('user/dashboard/order/all');            


        }


    }
    return redirect('home');    
}
```

When an user logs in as `admin`, the user is redirected to the right page but when a user logs in as `operator`, the user is redirected to `return redirect('home');`  instead of `return redirect('user/dashboard/home');`.

Why is this happening please?

Comment: Please clearify when which middleware is used. As first impression it looks like the `if (Auth::check())` statement in `AuthenticateUsers.php` returns `false`.

Comment: @ThomasVanderVeen, when user logs in ,`AuthenticateUsers.php` is used.  but in my routes, i use the `admin` and `user` middleware respectively

Comment: @XamarinDevil why do you have 2 middlewares?which is not working ?what is the code from `AuthenticateUsers.php` used for? in what middleware/class is your problem ?

Comment: I agree with Madalinivascu, I'm sure you can use just one place to do this kind of logic. However try to `var_dump(); die;` or `dd();` every if statement and see what if statement is not giving the desired result.